# How to get .mov file from gallery? mov file process working fine in android 8.1

Tags: android, bitmap, android-4.4-kitkat, android-8.1-oreo

By default android 8.1.0 .mov file processing is working fine. How get a .mov file from a gallery in lower version?

```
File[] file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
 try {
     for (File aFile : file) {
         if (!aFile.isDirectory()) {
             if (aFile.getName().endsWith(".mov")) {
                 Log.e("VIDEO_FILE=====", aFile.getAbsolutePath());
                 Uri uri_mov = Uri.parse(aFile.getAbsolutePath());
                 mediaList.add(new ExternalMediaFileBean(uri_mov, false));

             }
         } 
     }
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

// To get Thumb and display image
    Here I try to get Thumb value in lower version doesn't support this method. could you please suggest something.mov file process working fine in android 8.1.

```
  public void image_LoaderForURI(Uri uri, SimpleDraweeView imageView) {
                    ImageRequest request =
                            ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
                                    .setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(150, 150))
                                    .build();
                    DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                            .setImageRequest(request)
                           .setOldController(imageView.getController())
                            .build();
                    imageView.setController(controller);
                }
```

Comment: So, what happens in the other versions?

Comment: only I  get .mov file path..there is no thumb available.

Comment: Bitmap bitmap2 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(String.valueOf(uriArrayList.get(position).getMedia_uri()), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
>> here am trying to get video thumb .still i get empty bitmap..